# How to use OR within a IF Statement in Formula field

Tags: formula-field

I am trying to use the following code snippet in a formula field. I am confused on how i would represent OR within a IF statement

```
if(project_type__c == 'Billed' || project_type__c == 'UnBilled')
{
   //do something
}
else
{
   //do something
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use the IF function with `||` like you're used to:

```
IF(project_type__c  == 'Billed' || project_type__c == 'UnBilled', 'true', 'false')
```

Note that if your field `project_type__c` is a picklist, you need to enclose them in a TEXT() function:

```
IF(TEXT(project_type__c)  == 'Billed' || TEXT(project_type__c) == 'UnBilled', 'true', 'false')
```

Comment: IF(OR(project_type__c  == 'Billed', project_type__c == 'UnBilled'), 'true', 'false') is this acceptable?

Comment: Yes, that'd work too.

Answer (score 1):

```
IF (ISPICKVAL(project_type__c  , "Billed") || ISPICKVAL(project_type__c  , "Billed"),true value,false value )
```

If the value is text means Place the values in double quotes

Add "true value"

"false value"